# Anylogic resource pool capacity while on linking with slider

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to make my resource pool available/not available as per  defined on/off schedule.
Anylogic asks the capacity when on, i have mentioned it as 2.
But i want it to be connected with a slider so that capacity while on can also be made variable while running the model to  test the effects.

when i am trying to link the slider, my desired resource pool gets "disabled".
only those resource poolss are shown as enabled whose capacities are defined as "Direct" but not by schedule.
what to do?

Comment: Do you use `myResource.set_capacity()` function?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want a schedule-based resource pool to be linked with the slider. This is not possible, it is either schedule-based or "direct" (and then you can use the slider and the code Yashar suggests)

Answer (score 0):

You can link the field ***Capacity when on*** of a resource pool dynamically with the current value of a slider using the function `slider.getIntValue()`.

Please note however, that the resource pool capacity can't be changed for the current active shift (when the on/off-schedule is currently "on"). So for example, if your shift is currently active with a capacity of 2 and you changed the slider value to let's say 3, the result will be:

- Capacity during the current "on" shift: 2
- Capacity during the next "on" shift: 3